# self.__WB_MANIFEST is not replaced by InjectManifest generated urls for precaching using service worker

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin

This is my webpack config

```
    new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './app/service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'sw.js',
      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
    }),
```

This is my servie-worker.js

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { cleanupOutdatedCaches, precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
cleanupOutdatedCaches();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);
```

This is how i register serviceworker

```
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';

const register = () => {
  // service worker should be installed only in prod env.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    return;
  }
  // check if browser supports SW before register.
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const wb = new Workbox('/company/sw.js');

    wb.register().then((registration) => {
      console.log('Registration success', registration.scope);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Registration failed', err);
    });
  }
};

register();
```

This is the sw.js code generated by webpack bundler using InjectManifest where it injects the route by replacing self.__WB_MANIFEST

```
    f81121bb716d06db5a3c: function (e, t, r) {
        "use strict";
        var n = r("ee2c850f71b22ec627d9"),
            a = r("71160463eb5f8808d43e");
        (0, n.skipWaiting)(), (0, n.clientsClaim)(), (0, a.cleanupOutdatedCaches)(), (0, a.precacheAndRoute)([{
            'revision': 'd6d49a7c4da3232a63313d0296cb697c',
            'url': '/company/index.html'
        },  {
            'revision': null,
            'url': '/company/static/js/main.eecf38c8e0bdeb9edfd0.chunk.js'
        }, {
            'revision': 'd77aa54cfc47caccf631a032dccdd1a4',
            'url': '/company/static/js/main.eecf38c8e0bdeb9edfd0.chunk.js.br'
        }, {
            'revision': 'f583ac2ae2e839d40f7390f44de0d09e',
            'url': '/company/static/js/main.eecf38c8e0bdeb9edfd0.chunk.js.gz'
        }, {
            'revision': null,
            'url': '/company/static/js/node_vendors.dfc2f2b312f9103e4f57.chunk.js'
        }, {
            'revision': 'cc71224b8f04e2722f7fd8e934625d99',
            'url': '/company/static/js/node_vendors.dfc2f2b312f9103e4f57.chunk.js.br'
        }, {
            'revision': 'a66582b83e005784db6aa640e3075f67',
            'url': '/company/static/js/node_vendors.dfc2f2b312f9103e4f57.chunk.js.gz'
        }, {
            'revision': null,
            'url': '/company/static/js/runtime~main.67d1bc90b93c84b2daf6.js'
        }, {
            'revision': 'e0a95983d322b621a7fd3b16888aaa8b',
            'url': '/company/sw.js.br'
        }, {
            'revision': 'e1ab2a71f411919e92a90675915af0ef',
            'url': '/company/sw.js.gz'
        }] || [])
    },
```

Below is the screenshot of sw.js code from devtools when served from localhost
[image]

As we could clearly see in the sw.js file served in localhost, the self.__WB_MANIFEST is not replaced by the urls generated by InjectManifest. Here my question is how come the sw.js file is having different code from what its generated by bundler. I tried unregister service worker and tried empty cache as well still there is difference in sw.js from what i have in build vs what served. Please suggest some ideas here.
Below is the version im using

```
    "workbox-core": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-window": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a days effort I figured out where I went wrong. Previously my webpack config was like this

```
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.7,
    }),

    new BrotliPlugin({
      asset: '[path].br[query]',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.7,
    }),
        new InjectManifest({
      // exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
      // importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
      swSrc: './app/service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'sw.js',
      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
    }),
```

Now I moved InjectManifest plugin before the compressions plugin which eventually solved the problem

```
    new InjectManifest({
      // exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
      // importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
      swSrc: './app/service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'sw.js',
      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
    }),

    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.7,
    }),

    new BrotliPlugin({
      asset: '[path].br[query]',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.7,
    }),
```

Anyone has idea on how webpack handle this when making a bundle